# "heroku run rails db:seed" stops without finishing ("State changed from up to complete")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6, heroku-postgres

I'm using Rails 6.0.2.2 with PostgreSQL 12.1. I've been trying to deploy my Rails app on Heroku, but when I run "heroku run rails db:seed", the seeding process stops without completing. If I check the logs, all it says is:

```
2020-04-19T04:47:10.789255+00:00 heroku[run.1139]: State changed from up to complete
```

But it never finished running the seed file. By adding print statements in the seed file, I can see that it always stops at the same place, where it's inserting (fairly large) amounts of data into the database. However, I don't see an out-of-memory or other error anywhere.

What might be the problem, or where can I find more information about what might be causing the problem?

Comment: Can you try removing that fairly large amount of data or split that into chunks?

Comment: Ah. It works if I remove the bulk of the data... :/ That's unfortunate

Comment: I'm not sure what that bulk data exactly is, but can't you split that into multiple insertions? so you can debug if it's a size problem or something wrong with some part of the data.

Comment: !! Thanks for your help! I did what you said and it works now :) I had been using a gem called activerecord-import to import all of the records for a relation at once, which worked for smaller records. But for whatever reason, I ended up having to save larger records one-by-one to get it working on Heroku.